# Force classes to contain/use their own specific implementation of an abstract class

Tags: c#, inheritance, console, tui

I'm developing a TUI library in C# and I need advice on how to do color themes for display objects.  Objects that can be drawn on the screen all inherit from this interface:

```
public interface IDrawable
    {
        Area ScreenArea { get; }
        List<char[]> DisplayChars { get; }
        //some other properties...

    }
```

Or rather, more specifically, the interfaces for each drawable object implements this interface (`IWindow` is a `IDrawable`). Each `IDrawable` is drawn on a specified part of the console window represented by the Area struct:

```
public struct Area
    {
        public readonly int EndX;
        public readonly int EndY;
        public readonly int Height;
        public readonly int StartX;
        public readonly int StartY;
        public readonly int Width;

        public Area(int startX, int endX, int startY, int endY)
        {
            StartX = startX;
            EndX = endX;
            StartY = startY;
            EndY = endY;
            Height = endY - startY;
            Width = endX - startX;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the overlapping area between this area and another.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="refArea"></param>
        /// <returns>Overlap area relative to the upper left corner of the ref area.</returns>
        public Area OverlapWith(Area refArea)
        {
            //....
        }
    }
```

The actual drawing of objects is handled by methods in a static `Display` class, which call `Console.Write()` on each element in DisplayChars. I would like for each class that inherits from `IDrawable` to be forced to implement its own rules for how its area can be divided into separate areas of color, for example, popup windows might have separate colorable areas for its outer borders, its title (within its outer border), and its inner area.

I've been tossing over how to do this in my head for a while now.  I need to make a type, `ColorScheme`, to contain the rules for what characters to write in what color.  I decided the best way to do this would be to make it an abstract class, which contains a list of "sub-areas" that colors can be applied to separately.

I'd like for each non-abstract `IDrawable` to have to implement its own class inheriting from `ColorScheme`.  For instance, the abstract `Window : IWindow` class would have no such implementation, but `PopupWindow : Window` class would have to have a corresponding type of `PopupWindowColorScheme : ColorScheme` in which the author of `PopupWindow` would define how to split the class' `Area` into separate regions.  Each `PopupWindow` would have its own instance of this type to contain its specific colors.

Is this possible? If not, is there another way to force authors of `IDrawable` types to specify a method for splitting up their areas into colorable regions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't force each `IDrawable` to have a *unique* implementation of `ColorScheme` (e.g. multiple different implementations of `IDrawable` could use `PopupWindowColorScheme`). However, you can use [generic type constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) to add additional requirements for implementing your interface, like this:

```
public interface IDrawable<TColorScheme> 
    where TColorScheme : ColorScheme
{
    Area ScreenArea { get; }
    List<char[]> DisplayChars { get; }
    //some other properties...
    TColorScheme ColorScheme { get; }
}
```

Now, every implementation of `IDrawable` needs to specify a type of `ColorScheme` to use. But a consumer could just implement `IDrawable<ColorScheme>` which sort of defeats the purpose (depending on your requirements). We can go a little further:

```
public interface IDrawable<TColorScheme> 
    where TColorScheme : ColorScheme, new()
{
}

public abstract class ColorScheme {  }
```

Here, since `ColorScheme` is abstract, and the generic type constraint requires the provided type parameter to implement a parameterless constructor (`new()`), `ColorScheme` itself cannot be used as a parameter. Any implementing class would need to specify a custom implementation of `ColorScheme` that provides a public, parameterless constructor.

But we can go even further:

```
public interface IDrawable { } 
public interface IDrawable<TDrawable, TColorScheme> : IDrawable
    where TDrawable : IDrawable, new()
    where TColorScheme : ColorScheme<TDrawable>, new()
{
    object ScreenArea { get; }
    List<char[]> DisplayChars { get; }
    //some other properties...
    TColorScheme ColorScheme { get; }
}

public abstract class ColorScheme<TDrawable>
    where TDrawable : IDrawable, new()
{
}
```

Here, each implementation of `IDrawable` has to specify what `ColorScheme` it uses ***and*** each `ColorScheme` also has to specify what `IDrawable` it applies to. And because each requires a parameterless constructor, neither would be able to specify the common base type. Implementing this now looks a bit strange:

```
public class MyDrawable : IDrawable<MyDrawable, MyColorScheme> { }

public class MyColorScheme : ColorScheme<MyDrawable> { }
```

It's still possible to implement a reusable `ColorScheme` or `IDrawable`, (e.g. `MyOtherDrawable : MyDrawable` uses `MyColorScheme`). However, in my opinion, this is starting to get rather cumbersome and tedious to implement. In general, unless you have technical reasons why you *have* use a type constraint, I'd avoid using it, as you'll often find it too limiting in the future.

Comment: This should be perfect! Thank you for the quick response :) Now I just have to figure the innards of what a ColorScheme should look like, preferably in such a way that the Draw methods don't have to check and set color for each character they write to the screen.

Comment: Hmm, slight problem, on account of poor inheritance hierarchy design.  I currently have interfaces for abstract classes inheriting from `IDrawable`, and specific types inheriting indirectly through their abstract base with the idea that classes like `WindowManager` and `ControlManager` should be able to handle their respective types through their interfaces, and still treat them as drawables. Would it be too terrible to use casting and rely on those who create custom types to, e.g., use both `IDrawable` and `IWindow` when creating a new window type, as they are supposed to?

Comment: @thetiniestmouse In that case, I'd recommend keeping a non-generic interface `IDrawable` that specifies all the core properties and methods *other* than `ColorScheme` and a sub-interface `IDrawable<T> : IDrawable` that provides `ColorScheme`-specific functionality. You can even have a property on `IDrawable` that exposes the base `ColorScheme` and hide it `IDrawable<T>` with `new T ColorScheme { get; }`. (This is similar to how `IEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable` works)

Comment: This would mean that the lowest-level types like `PopupWindow` would inherit from `IDrawable` through their base's interface, and `IDrawable<T>` through themselves, yes? Other than being a bit redundant, is there any way this could cause trouble? (You can probably tell, this is the sort of project one does for self-instruction more than anything else, haha.)

Comment: @thetiniestmouse Correct. I'm thinking `PopupWindow : Window, IDrawable<PopupWindowColorScheme>`. There's no problem with this style of API. You might consider different naming options to make things feel less redundant and more natural, e.g. instead of `IDrawable<T>` maybe `IHasColorScheme<T>` or `IColorSchemeDrawable<T>`.

Comment: Take a look at dependency injection. That gives you the option to make each `IDrawable` depend on `IColorScheme` but keep the logic to determine which implementation separate. At one one point in the application you would configure which implementations of IDrawable used which implementations of IColorScheme. You don't want a class to figure out its own dependencies. A class should just depend on something (like an interface) and then something else determines which implementation to use. DI containers like Windsor or Autofac manage all that.

Comment: @ScottHannen Good recommendation (especially since this is a self-education project), though I personally prefer [MEF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx) these days.

Comment: The problem isn't poor inheritance hierarchy design. It's that good inheritance hierarchy design is inherently difficult (no pun intended.) It creates problems like the one you're trying to solve. There's the expression "favor composition over inheritance." Write classes that do what you need and combine them instead of trying to arrange them in a hierarchy of inherited classes.

Comment: @ScottHannen That's an excellent way of putting it.  I'm trying to design this project to get used to using S.O.L.I.D. and other good design practices, and very early on I realized that to adhere to single responsibility, more complex objects (like a window) really have to just be big aggregates of other types. Frankly I'm wondering if my inheritance is too deep, perhaps I should eliminate `IWindow` and `IControl` and have managers for those types work with the abstract base instead. Looking into DI and MEF for sure, looks like a good alternative for some stuff I've been using reflection for.